# Weak * Compactness and Local Compactness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm reading through Murphy's C* Algebras, and the following theorem is presented:

If $A$ is an abelian Banach algebra, then the set of characters $\Omega(A)$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.  If $A$ is unital, then $\Omega(A)$ is compact.

Proof: It's easily checked that $\Omega(A) \cup \{0\}$ is weak* closed in the weak * compact closed unit ball $S$ of $A^*$.  Thus, $\Omega(A) \cup \{0\}$ is weak * compact implying that $\Omega(A)$ is locally compact.  If $A$ is unital, then $\Omega(A)$ is weak * closed in $S$, and hence $\Omega(A)$ is compact.

So I have two main questions here.

1. Why does weak * compactness of $\Omega(A) \cup \{0\}$ imply local compactness of $\Omega(A)$?
2. Does the term "compact" is the last sentence of the proof mean weak* compact?  If not, what does it mean simply by compact?

I'm brand new to this subject, so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Note that $\Omega(A)$ is open in $\Omega(A)\cup\{0\}$. Then invoke the general fact that open subspaces of locally compact spaces are again locally compact.

(2) Yes, compact here means compact in the weak$^*$-topology.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome reply.  One quick question.  Why is O(A) u {0} locally compact?  Is that a consequence of it being weak * compact?

Comment: @Isochron A space $X$ is locally compact if every point $x \in X$ has a compact neighborhood. If $X$ is compact, then the space $X$ itself is a compact neighborhood of $x \in X$. Hence, it is trivially locally compact.

Comment: Okay thank you!